# Is there a statement from Gygax on the origin of the Unseen Servant spell?

Tags: spells, history-of-gaming, adnd-1e, designer-reasons

Poul Anderson's *[Three Hearts and Three Lions](https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/EB/A/Anderson,%20Poul%20-%20Three%20Hearts%20and%20Three%20Lions.pdf)* is is cited in Appendix N of the original *Dungeon Master's Guide* as one of the inspirations for D&D, and is an influential source that [contributed to many of the game's idiosyncratic ideas](http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2019/03/more-from-three-hearts-and-three-lions.html).

When I read it, I first thought that it must be the source for the *Unseen Servant* spell, which first appeard in AD&D 1e: The magician Martinus Trismegistus (also the town's apothecary, dentist, scribe, dowser and horse doctor) has a magic shop with an invisible servant that serves a bottle of wine and goblets (p. 100). This is how I tpyically employ Unseen Servant for town mages in my games. And indeed, [Literary Sources of D&D](http://www.hahnlibrary.net/rpgs/sources.html), as well as [Spells through the Ages](http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2017/02/spells-through-ages-unseen-servant-and.html) by Delta both conject that this may be the case.

However, the wizard talks to the servant as one would to a creature, and apparently the servant is asleep at first:

> He dumped books from chairs, muttering something apologetic about his house-keeper, and piped aloud, 'Wine! Bring wine for three.' After a short silence: 'Hi, there! I say, do wake up! Wine for three.'

and later on, he waits until the "*invisible servant had presumably left*" before referring to the servant as a sprite:

> 'I declare there is no decent help to be had these days. None. That sprite now, he is quite impossible. Improbable at least,'

Sprites are a monster in D&D 1e (p. 92, *MM*) and have the ability to become *invisible* at will. Martinus later (p. 103) also states he can summon sprites. All of this would rather seem to support that Martinus has summoned an invisible sprite that serves him, and is not using a spell that creates "a force rather than a creature" and that does not need sleep, at all.

So, is there any statement from Gygax (or anyone who directly interacted with him and would know) where he got the idea for Unseen Servant from?

Comment: A reminder to everyone that Designer Reasons questions require support - guesses are not supported answers, no matter how educated they may be.

Comment: @NautArch-is-skeptical-about-SE This seems to limit any answer to a direct quote? Since a well-supported answer with a conclusion would still be a "well educated guess" unless confirmed by Gygax or someone near him.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Exactly - We're asking for the reason a designer did something, we need to hear from that designer. Anything else is conjecture.

Comment: @NautArch-is-skeptical-about-SE Arguably, secondary sources may be applicable here as well, as in “I talked to Gary about this in 1997 and he said blah blah”.  But yes, an answer should be making some claim about something Gygax actually said.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it may not be so easy to dredge up some direct or indirect source from Dragonsfoot or some old Dragon mag or some interview with one of the early players, that is why the question is here. The speculation that its from 3H&3L is not implausible, even with all the sprite business; but as this is just inference, I hope there could be some more direct support from where the spell came from. And if nobody can find any, then "There is no info on this" might be the (less satisfying) answer. Maybe QuadraticWizard knows -- they have an amazing command of the games history.

Comment: I would say no answer means don't submit any answer. Just because you can't find something doesn't mean someone else wouldn't.